# How to insert data from Excel sheet to SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

I have an Excel sheet now I need to insert data from that sheet into SQL Server 2005.

I need to create a temp table and insert data into that table. The database name is `Employee`

Can you pls  provide me the syntax for achieving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple search: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/321686

Probably easiest is

```
SELECT *
INTO #tmptable
FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\test\xltest.xls', [SheetName$])
```

Answer (score 2):

```
--Excel 2007-2010


INSERT INTO DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLENAME
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0',
'Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;Database=C:\SheetName.xlsx','SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]');

--Excel 97-2003


INSERT INTO DATABASE.SCHEMA.TABLENAME
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.4.0',
'Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;Database=C:\SheetName.xls','SELECT * FROM [SheetName$]');
```