# Export Excel data into SQL Server table in asp.net c#

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, excel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to insert data from Excel sheet to SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141521/how-to-insert-data-from-excel-sheet-to-sql-server-2005)

I have an Excel sheet like below

Country name         Port        01/01/05        02/01/05

geria            Arw     25000       10000

That data should insert into a table like this

```
CountryName     Port        date            cal
1    geria          Arw     01/01/05        25000
2    geria          Arw     02/01/05        10000
```

How can I insert this type of data into datatable?

Comment: SQL Server table or [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)?

Answer (score 0):

Open a SQLConnection object to the database in the usual way.

Execute the following SQL command, using a SQLCommand object (in the usual way):

```
INSERT INTO myTable (CountryName, Port, date, cal)
VALUES ('geria', 'Arw', '2005-01-01 12:00:00 AM', 25000)
```

Comment: But how can i insert from excel to sqlserver? because in excel sheet i have multiple date with not fixed header and that date i want to add in database in date field.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141521/how-to-insert-data-from-excel-sheet-to-sql-server-2005

Comment: Thanks @Robert Harvey.But In excel sheet i have a columnname "'01/01/05' and '02/01/05'" like this and this value insert table into date column field into database

Comment: That sounds like a "crosstab" report.  You may have to write a program to import that, since the data goes in a horizontal direction and you will probably need to insert it into the database vertically.  But it would be hard to tell from your question; you didn't volunteer this information before.

Comment: By writing some code, @sejal.